# Uncaught ReferenceError: wNumb is not defined in Laravel 10 for Price Range Slider With jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-10

Getting the error in the console as Uncaught ReferenceError: wNumb is not defined on the Shop page and the news-flash is also stopped flashing.

Please find below the screenshot for the reference;

[image]

I am getting errors at two places in main.js file located at public\frontend\assets\js\main.js

Please find the screenshots as below;

[image]

[image]

I have placed two script tags one as wNumb.min.js and the second as nouislider.min.js but still I am getting the error as **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')** which can be seen in the below screenshot;

[image]

*shop_page.blade.php*

```
    @extends('frontend.master_dashboard')
    @section('main')
     
    @section('title')
    Shop Page
    @endsection
     
     
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wnumb/1.2.0/wNumb.min.js" integrity="sha512-igVQ7hyQVijOUlfg3OmcTZLwYJIBXU63xL9RC12xBHNpmGJAktDnzl9Iw0J4yrSaQtDxTTVlwhY730vphoVqJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
     
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/15.7.0/nouislider.min.js" integrity="sha512-UOJe4paV6hYWBnS0c9GnIRH8PLm2nFK22uhfAvsTIqd3uwnWsVri1OPn5fJYdLtGY3wB11LGHJ4yPU1WFJeBYQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
     
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
    <div class="page-header mt-30 mb-50">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="archive-header">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <h5 class="mb-15">Shop Page</h5>
                        <div class="breadcrumb">
                            <a href="{{ url('/') }}" rel="nofollow"><i class="fi-rs-home mr-5"></i>Home</a>
                            <span></span> Shop Page
                        </div>
                    </div>
     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-lg-1-5 primary-sidebar sticky-sidebar">

            <!-- Filter By Price -->

            <div class="sidebar-widget price_range range mb-30">

                <form method="post" action="{{ route('shop.filter') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <h5 class="section-title style-1 mb-30">Fill by price</h5>
                    <div class="price-filter">
                        <div class="price-filter-inner">
                            

                            <div id="slider-range" class="price-filter-range" data-min="0" data-max="2000"></div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="price_range" id="price_range" value="">

                            <input type="text" id="amount" value="AED 0 - AED 2000" readonly="">

                            <br><br>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="border-radius: 4px;"><i class="fi-rs-filter mr-5"></i>Filter</button>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (){

        if ($('#slider-range').length > 0) {

            const max_price = parseInt($('#slider-range').data('max'));
            const min_price = parseInt($('#slider-range').data('min'));
            let price_range = min_price+"-"+max_price;

            let price = price_range.split('-');

            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: min_price,
                max: max_price,
                values: price,

                slide: function (event, ui) {

                    $("#amount").val('AED'+ui.values[0]+"-"+'AED'+ui.values[1]);
                    $("#price_range").val(ui.values[0]+"-"+ui.values[1]);
                }
            });
        }



    })


</script>
```

*master_dashboard.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

@php
$seo = App\Models\Seo::find(1);
@endphp

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="title" content="{{ $seo->meta_title }}" />
    <meta name="author" content="{{ $seo->meta_author }}" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ $seo->meta_keyword }}" />
    <meta name="description" content="{{ $seo->meta_description }}" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />
    <!-- Favicon -->  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('frontend/assets/imgs/theme/favicon.svg') }}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <!-- Template CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('frontend/assets/css/plugins/animate.min.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('frontend/assets/css/main.css?v=5.3') }}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.css" >

    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Modal -->

    <!-- Quick view -->
    @include('frontend.body.quickview')

    <!-- Header  -->
    @include('frontend.body.header')

    <!-- End Header  -->


    <main class="main">
        @yield('main')

    </main>

    <!-- Footer  -->

    @include('frontend.body.footer')




    <!-- Preloader Start -->
    <div id="preloader-active">
        <div class="preloader d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <div class="preloader-inner position-relative">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/imgs/theme/loading.gif') }}" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Vendor JS-->
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.6.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/vendor/jquery-migrate-3.3.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/slick.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/jquery.syotimer.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/waypoints.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/wow.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/magnific-popup.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/counterup.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/jquery.countdown.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/images-loaded.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/isotope.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/scrollup.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/jquery.vticker-min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/jquery.theia.sticky.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/plugins/jquery.elevatezoom.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Template  JS -->
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/main.js?v=5.3') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/shop.js?v=5.3') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('frontend/assets/js/script.js') }}"></script>

 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

*main.js*

```
(function ($) {
    ("use strict");
    // Page loading
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        $("#preloader-active").delay(450).fadeOut("slow");
        $("body").delay(450).css({
            overflow: "visible"
        });
        $("#onloadModal").modal("show");
    });
    /*-----------------
        Menu Stick
    -----------------*/
    var header = $(".sticky-bar");
    var win = $(window);
    win.on("scroll", function () {
        var scroll = win.scrollTop();
        if (scroll < 200) {
            header.removeClass("stick");
            $(".header-style-2 .categories-dropdown-active-large").removeClass("open");
            $(".header-style-2 .categories-button-active").removeClass("open");
        } else {
            header.addClass("stick");
        }
    });

    /*------ ScrollUp -------- */
    $.scrollUp({
        scrollText: '<i class="fi-rs-arrow-small-up"></i>',
        easingType: "linear",
        scrollSpeed: 900,
        animation: "fade"
    });

    /*------ Wow Active ----*/
    new WOW().init();

    //sidebar sticky
    if ($(".sticky-sidebar").length) {
        $(".sticky-sidebar").theiaStickySidebar();
    }

    // Slider Range JS
    if ($("#slider-range").length) {
        $(".noUi-handle").on("click", function () {
            $(this).width(50);
        });
        var rangeSlider = document.getElementById("slider-range");
        var moneyFormat = wNumb({
            decimals: 0,
            thousand: ",",
            prefix: "$"
        });
        noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider, {
            start: [500, 1000],
            step: 1,
            range: {
                min: [0],
                max: [2000]
            },
            format: moneyFormat,
            connect: true
        });

        // Set visual min and max values and also update value hidden form inputs
        rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on("update", function (values, handle) {
            document.getElementById("slider-range-value1").innerHTML = values[0];
            document.getElementById("slider-range-value2").innerHTML = values[1];
            document.getElementsByName("min-value").value = moneyFormat.from(values[0]);
            document.getElementsByName("max-value").value = moneyFormat.from(values[1]);
        });
    }
 
    /*--- VSticker ----*/
    $("#news-flash").vTicker({
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        animation: "fade",
        mousePause: false,
        showItems: 1
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified with the new changes to the main.js file ;

**Before:**

```
document.getElementById("slider-range-value1").innerHTML = values[0];
document.getElementById("slider-range-value2").innerHTML = values[1];
```

**Now:**

```
rangeSlider.noUiSlider.min = values[0];
rangeSlider.noUiSlider.max = values[1];
```

The code for the Slider Range JS is as below;

```
// Slider Range JS
    if ($("#slider-range").length) {
        $(".noUi-handle").on("click", function () {
            $(this).width(50);
        });
        var rangeSlider = document.getElementById("slider-range");
        var moneyFormat = wNumb({
            decimals: 0,
            thousand: ",",
            prefix: "$"
        });
        noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider, {
            start: [500, 1000],
            step: 1,
            range: {
                min: [0],
                max: [2000]
            },
            format: moneyFormat,
            connect: true
        });
 
        // Set visual min and max values and also update value hidden form inputs
        rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on("update", function (values, handle) {
            rangeSlider.noUiSlider.min = values[0];
            rangeSlider.noUiSlider.max = values[1];
            document.getElementsByName("min-value").value = moneyFormat.from(values[0]);
            document.getElementsByName("max-value").value = moneyFormat.from(values[1]);
        });
    }
```